# How to change my IP address?

Tags: internet, ip

THe internet of where I live is controlled and filtered. I mean it does not let me connect to some servers using my real IP so I need to use a different IP address.Is it possible to change my IP manually?

Comment: Look for: Tor or VPN this is most likely what will help you out. Note you don't need a new address, you need to route through somebody else.

Comment: I think, you need a proxy: https://www.google.bg/search?q=open+page+through+proxy&rlz=1C1CHBD_enBG704BG704&oq=open+page+through&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.13579j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Changing IP address is a wrong approach for this, proxies and VPN are the right tools.

Comment: there is a problem and that is the proxies themselves are filtered

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. However, since you need to change the IP address to static, the only way is to set-up a manual/static IP editing the /etc/network/interfaces file. for that you need to edit the interfaces file with;

```
sudo nano /etc/network/intarfaces
```

You'll ideally see something like;

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Replace it with;

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address x.x.x.x
netmask x.x.x.x
gateway x.x.x.x
```

Moving further, if you have or require domain to be resolved along with DNS servers, you may add few more lines to the file, similar to;

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address x.x.x.x
netmask x.x.x.x
gateway x.x.x.x
dns-search example.com
dns-nameservers x.x.x.x x.x.x.x
```

Please note, there are two sets of x.x.x.x within the DNS name servers (Primary and Secondary) with a space. You may use one pair or both depending on your requirement.

To save the file select ctrl+o, -> enter and exit with ctrl+x.

And then just to be sure, simple restart the interface with;

```
sudo ifdown eth0           # wait for sometime
sudo ifup eth0             # and then issue this to restart
```

Also, as a final step, simply type below to confirm the interface change;

```
ifconfig -a
```

**Alternative way;**

Refer to your server or the device which responds to DHCP requests and add a reservation, in case if you do not like to play with the server, files.. etc.

In order to get the MAC address for reservation, simply check the interface information with a;

which should ideally display something similar to below;

```
ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:c5:4a:16:5a  
          inet addr:10.0.0.100  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:c5ff:fe4a:165a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:466475604 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:403172654 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2574778386 (2.5 GB)  TX bytes:1618367329 (1.6 GB)
          Interrupt:16
```

Where you see the `HWaddr 00:15:c5:4a:16:5a` and assign it to the DHCP reservation.

Hope this helps!